# Using C# API controller I need to merge items with same ID into one

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, model-view-controller

I do not normally work with C#, yet there is a problem I have to solve.
I have a DB which returns multiple rows for each document if this document has more than 1 row of data and I have no way of changing the way it works.
Yet I need to display each document only as total of all rows.
I would like to incorporate my API Controller to iterate over all items, check if they have same ID and if so add values for specific fields while keeping some of them unchanged.

Something like:
If these are the list objects
{ ID: 1, Account: ABC, Value: 200 },
{ ID: 1, Account: ABC, Value: 50 },
{ ID: 2, Account: BCD, Value: 150 },
Then this will be the output
{ ID: 1, Account: ABC, Value: 250 },
{ ID: 2, Account: BCD, Value: 150 },

Here is my Controller code:

```
var List = await (from s in _context.tbl1
                // Join tbl2 table as t context
                join t in _context.tbl2 on s.Ref equals t.Ref
                // Join tbl3 table as u context
                join u in _context.tbl3 on s.Account equals u.Account
                where s.Account == id
                // Use View Model
                select new ViewModel
                {
                    ID = s.Ref,
                    Account = s.Account,
                    Name = u.Name,
                    Date = s.Date,
                    Value = t.Value
                }).ToListAsync();
```

If this is not a good idea I can always do it on the front end side, but I would like to impact front end in the least ways possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
list.GroupBy(g => g.ID).Select(x => new { 
    ID = x.Key,
    Account = x.Select(c => c.Account).FirstOrDefault(),
    Value = x.Sum(c => c.Value)
    });
```

[You can see my example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CLU8b3)